# ¿Cómo puedo instalar Angular Generator en VS Code?

Tags: angular, vscode

En la primera guía de Angular https://angular.io/start, muestran la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo instalar esa extensión en VS Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso es una captura de [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ttnsfv). Que es un editor online de prueba que te permite crear código rápido.

Pero hay esta extension para vscode que te permite hacer algo similar a lo que estas buscando!
[cyrilletuzi.angular-schematics](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cyrilletuzi.angular-schematics)

Comment: Por favor considera leer [answer], los aportes que son solo enlaces se consideran de baja calidad

Comment: Por favor Jordi edita tu respuesta, revisa [answer], agrega lo esencial del enlace que compartes, saludos.